# Bootstrap columns bug

Tags: bootstrap-4

I started creating blog system layout with Bootstrap, but i have a bug with the columns in the main class, i tried to solve it, but i can't, i tried many grid codes. Here is screenshot with the bug:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ECYL.jpg
I want the second left column to be aligned under the first one, but it can't, and can put anything in the right column, if I try, it goes in the bottom of the page. I used this Bootstrap source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ 
Give me some ideas or solutions for this bug

Comment: where is your code? edit your question and add it there

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row" backgroud="#D3D3D3">
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="card md-4">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/750x300" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">
          Черен сняг
        </h2>
        <p class="card-text">
          "Кълбото на планетата плуваше в чернотата под „Пурпурно сияние“. Изглеждаше някак унило и сиво, като мърлява снежна топка. Висеше си там самотно и сякаш се чудеше дали да приеме малката совалка, или да я изгори в атмосферата си. В космическия кораб фигурки в скафандри се суетяха около сребристата машина за изследователски и подсветлинни полети, включваха и изключваха кабели, товареха контейнери.На мостика на кораба-майка навигатор Тар показваше на капитана и старшите офицери триизмерна холограма.
          – След хиперскока минахме покрай Х-4А, която, знаете, е забранена за изследвания и кацане, после влязохме в ниска "
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Прочети повече  ></a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        "Публикувано на 01.01.2018 от"
        <a href="#">Admin</a>
      </div>
   </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px" >

  <div class="row" backgroud="#D3D3D3">
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="card md-4">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/750x300" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">
          Окото на бога 2
        </h2>
        <p class="card-text">
          "Окото на бога 2-  Помощ от ЕКА
          Джон се взира известно време в монитора, после изкрещя и бутна кафето си върху клавиатурата. Докато се опитваше да попие петната с носната си кърпа и проклинаше несръчността си, при него дотича шефът на екипа.
          – Ревеш като магаре, Джон, топките ли си свари с кафето?
          – Мамка му, не е това, виж само какво имаме тук – каза Джон развълнувано, сочейки екрана.  Ендрю Джаксън се наведе към "
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Прочети повече  ></a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        "Публикувано на 01.01.2018 от"
        <a href="#">Admin</a>
      </div>
   </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```